# how do remove original and replicate cases in data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
id    x2  x3  x4   x5
id1   3    6   5   4
id1   10   8   7   9
id2   11   6   8   4
id3   20  25   26  2
id4   10  2    4   9
id4   1   4    3   2
```

I found duplicate cases through duplicated(x). Now, I need to remove id1 and id4 as duplicates id and have a new data frame as follow:

```
id    x2  x3  x4   x5
id2   11   6   8   4
id3   20  25   26  2
```

how can I do it?

Comment: How did you use `duplicated`? You'll need to use it twice in order to remove the duplicated id values.

Comment: `df[!(duplicated(df$id) | duplicated(df$id, fromLast = TRUE)), ]`